# Is $\frac{w-1}{w+1}$ a conformal mapping from $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$ onto $\mathbb{C}\setminus\big((-\infty,-1]\cup[1,+\infty)\big)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, rational-functions, meromorphic-functions

Is the meromorphic function $g$ defined by $g(w) := \frac{w-1}{w+1}$ a conformal mapping from the singly slit plane $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$ onto the doubly slit plane $\mathbb{C}\setminus\big((-\infty,-1]\cup[1,+\infty)\big)$?

What does this imply about the map $h$, where
     $$h(w):=g(w^2)=\frac{w^2-1}{w^2+1}\,,$$ defined on the right half-plane $\text{Re}(w)>0$?

Comment: Tell us what you think, so that potential answerers can see what could be a useful answer.

Comment: Every Mobius transformation is a conformal mapping.  Since $g$ is one, it follows that $g$ is conformal.  It is left to see that $g$ maps bijectively your singly slit plane to the doubly slit plane.  For the second part, what is the image of the right half-plane under the squaring map $w\mapsto w^2$?